# Web Service works in IE7 but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, web-services, iis

I have a .Net web service that I call from javascript using:

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "http://myServerIP/Myervice.asmx/MyMethod",
                 data: "{}",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "jsonp",
                 success: function(msg) { alert('sucess ' + msg); },
                 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(XMLHttpRequest); alert(textStatus); alert(errorThrown); }
             });
```

I get a success message in IE7 and in Firefox I don't get any decent errors back just 'error' and 'undefined'

I suspect this is due to the fact that I'm on an Intranet here and IE7 is taking my credentials and passing them to IIS on 'myServer' on my behalf while other browsers cannot.

Is this the case?

How do I go about fixing this problem?

Thanks in advance

Davy

Comment: What does Firebug show as request/response?

Comment: I actually get nothing at all - sorry I know this doesn't help - must be something to do with what's happening I guess.

Comment: Response Headers
Content-Length 1758
Content-Type text/html
Server Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By ASP.NET
Date Wed, 25 Nov 2009 13:15:05 GMT

Comment: Request Headers
Host server
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5
Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive 300
Connection keep-alive
Origin http://localhost:2423
Access-Control-Request-Method POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers x-requested-with

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is something going on with the datatype 'jsonp'. [Read this](http://digitalmihailo.blogspot.com/2008/05/make-jsonp-work-in-firefox-chrome.html), try using a different datatype..